# What does "tweak left" mean?

Tags: shortcut

In Object Mode, the "Select" menu drops down to "Box Select."  The keyboard shortcut shown for this is "Tweak Left."

What does "Tweak Left" mean?  How am I supposed to use this keyboard shortcut (or mouse shortcut)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have a test build with a tweak patch. Yes, tweaking involves mouse.

> (...) **drag and let go via either left or right click**, which most applications have.

This means you click on an object, drag it while holding down the mouse key and release the key when you're done.

You may also read [the posts by a pansi and Fligh users](https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-modeling-tweak-mode-smart-highlighting/361218)

Comment: "*This means you click on an object, drag it while holding down the mouse key and release the key when you're done*", this seems to be the exact [definition of *to drag*](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/drag.htm).